# Trying to refresh div inside Iframe

Tags: javascript, php, partial-page-refresh

I have a section of my site im working on where i have a certain div, the div "comments" needs to be checked for blank comments being posted and remove them, it works fine the first time but after the div is refreshed it stops working. I'm trying to get this script to reload every second along with the div so the results stay consistent. Here are my 2 scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doRefresh(){
    $("#comments").load("comment.txt");
}
$(function() {
    setInterval(doRefresh, 1000);
});
</script>

<script>
setTimeout(refreshData, 1000);
function parent() 
{ $(".comment_name:empty").parent().hide()};
refreshData();
</script>
```

Comment: Loading the AJAX result may take more than a second, increasing the interval of `doRefresh` calls might help.

Comment: I just deleted the refresh so its static, i only need it for leaving comments and not needed as a chat room type box, but it would be nice if anyone had an answer for how to do this in the future. @Teemu, your answer was tried to no success sadly :(

Comment: Umh ... What actually "is not working"? How are you calling `parent` and what happens in `refreshData` ..?

Comment: I dont want to post the full code here as some of the info contained is confidential but honestly its no big deal, without a database im running into a bunch of issues. I just need to try a database out and it would solve a lot of these problems im having. Thank you anyway

Comment: Please check [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference you should have a look into websockets. This will enable you to have data refresh as it is entered from one browser to another and will always keep it up to date without refreshing.

Here is a reference for you to get started. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

It is a starting point and will help you a lot in future for dynamic content on multiple end points.

Comment: Thank you so much!